# When creating SQLite database for iPhone, how do I configure Z_METADATA and Z_PRIMARYKEY tables?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

I'm trying to create a new SQLite database for the iPhone using SQLite Manager firefox add-on. From what I understand, Z_METADATA AND Z_PRIMARYKEY tables must be included. How do I configure these though? I've tried to replicate a database by adding the same columns in each of these tables (for Z_METADATA --> Z_VERSION, Z_UUID, Z_PLIST for Z_PRIMARYKEY --> Z_ENT, Z_NAME, Z_SUPER, Z_MAX). Where I get confused is the Z_UUID.. how do I find the correct UUID for this column? Also, the "BLOB" part in Z_PLIST is a bit confusing.

Any help would be great. I've been searching for a solution for this for a quite a few days with no luck.

Thnx.

Answer (score 2):

Wait. Wot?

Are you trying to create a Core Data compatible database with some random SQLite database editing tool?

Yeah, don't do that.   It isn't supported, documented, and the details may change over time.  The database schema used by Core Data is not meant to be futzed with directly.